# Configuring Composer in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: php, netbeans, composer-php

Netbeans claims they support Composer in Netbeans 7.3.  However, I can confirm that I am running version 7.3, but there is no composer options in the PHP section of my preferences (running OSX 10.8.4)

Is there something else I have to do to get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out that for some reason in OSX, it didn't install the Composer module.  Don't know why, in Windows, it was installed from the get go.  I had to install it from plugins, and I had initially missed it because it was titled "PHP Composer" and I was looking for simply "Composer"

Answer (score 2):

just right click your project (the root of the directory tree) and you will see the composer menu

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm trying to say is that those menus are not there.  I see them in screenshots on the NetBeans Site, but not in my own.  Will try to get a screenshot.

Comment: If you look at screenshot [here](http://www.use.com/fc20d30c7782c39e6658)  you can see that I am on netbeans 7.3 and there's nothing in the context menu.  Thanks.